# Display Mongoose field name using Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

How can i display mongoose field name where the field value is true.

this is my json:

```
benefits: {
             hospitals: true,
             cashless_hospital: true,
             existing_disease_cover: true,
             copay: true,
             room_rent: true,
             percentage_pay_in_bill: true,
             restore_benefits: true,
             free_additional_cover: true,
             eye_cover: true,
             regular_medical_expense: true
         },
```

Using angularjs how can i display field name where the value is true.
Every fieldname in the benefits is Boolean datatype.

so i need to display fieldname where the value is TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in benefits">
    <span ng-if='value'>{{key}}</span>
</div>
```